# How to adjust according to different screen resolution

Tags: php, html

I have made this page with screen resolution 1366 x 768.The dashboard looks fine here but when i checked it on 1024 x 768 it got messy.Please help me! Here is the code.

```
<style>
  #heading{ 
    text-align:right;
    font-size: 20px;
    float:right;
    margin:50px 20px;
  }
</style>

<h1 align="center" style="position:absolute;top:30px; left:600px;">
  KARMA <br>(3-SEATER)
</h1>
<div id="heading">
  <a href="home.php" style="text-decoration:none;">Home</a>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <a href="pswd.php" style="text-decoration:none;">Change Password</a>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <a href="logout.php" style="text-decoration:none;">Logout</a>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <a href="UserManual.pdf" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;">Help</a>
</div>
```

Comment: if you make page with resolution`1366*768` than how will it look the same in `1024 x 768`??? you should google for `responsive html layout`.. and try learning `bootstrap`...

Comment: you needs a responsive CSS framework: `bootstrap`, `foundation`, `skeleton`, etc .....  there are many

Answer (score 0):

if you are using html5

you can add

```
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

to the `<head>` element
this will adjust the body content to the width of any device irrespective of resolution n all...

Answer (score 0):

You are after a *responsive* website. A responsive website is a site which changes layout depending on the size of the screen they are being displayed on.
There are a few different options when making your site responsive.

**Responsive Framework**

A responsive framework will help you to create responsive sites, [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), and [foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) are two key responsive frameworks widely used in responsive web design. If you are new to *bootstrap*, a website such as [shoelace](http://shoelace.io/) may help you to create a visual representation of the layout of the site on different devices

**Media Queries**

Media queries are used to display different style rules depending on the size of the screen. *Please note, they do not change the core HTML, just the style, however this can be used to show / hide elements.*
An example of a media query for a small perhaps mobile screen would be:

```
@media (max-width: 700px) { ... }
```

Any style rules you place in here will only be applied to the document when the width of the device is between *0 - 700 px*

[Read more on Media Queries here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

---

***Extra Note***

Responsive and mobile friendly websites are now even more important, with googles recent update, making mobile friendly websites rank better in searches. You can check if they consider your site *mobile friendly* [here](https://www.google.co.uk/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly/)